# The usage of "to"

Tags: word-usage

Why do we force/cause/encourage/compel things TO happen but we don't make things to happen, we just make things happen. Where's the "to"? Why?

Comment: We also ***want** things **to** happen*, but we ***hope** things happen* with no "infinitive marker". It's presumably just "established idiomatic preference" that's now so strong we can call it a grammatical rule (it's one way or the other for most verbs, but I expect there are some "uncertain" cases where either is okay).

Comment: Because we do. I'm sorry, but that is the whole of the answer. Language is as it is, not as somebody thinks it ought to be.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Note that we can also *hope **for** something **to** happen*.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why we don't use a **to**, but it's well documented for this meaning of 'make'. See this definition:

[make verb (CAUSE)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)

[+ infinitive **without to**]

> The ​wind is making my ​eyes ​water.
>
> What made you ​change ​your ​mind?
>
> Just ​seeing Woody Allen's ​face is enough to make me ​laugh.
>
> The ​photograph makes me ​look about 80!

It wasn't always like this: here is a sentence from Psalm 23 of the King James Bible (1611):

> He maketh me **to** lie down in green pastures

Answer (score 1):

Make is called a causative verb in English. None of them "take" to: These verbs are:-let-make-have-get-help/

Examples: I made him do his homework.
She let him come into the house.
He had her paint the room.
We got them the books from the library
They help him do this work.

Comment: Yes, but (archaically, KJV) [He maketh me **to** lie down in green pastures](http://biblehub.com/psalms/23-2.htm) And even today it's quite unexceptional to say *Alcohol helps me **to** sleep* as well as *It helps me sleep* with no infinitive marker.

Comment: The meaning of help him do his work and help him to do his work are not the same. The first means you are helping with the actual process of doing the work, the second means you do something that helps the person to do something on his or her own.

Comment: If you think that, I won't bother trying to convince you otherwise. But I don't agree.

Comment: Both are grammatical. Just like: I like TO play tennis. and I like playing tennis. Those too are slightly different in meaning. And like can "take to" or not. Just like help.